# How does the server send feeds when they are unique to each application?

Tags: java, client-server, feed

As the diagram suggests, there is one main server and more than one user application. Server in its database, has maintained a set of feeds for each application.In other words, each application will have a set of unique feeds.

[image]

How does the client application receive the feeds from the server ? The only problem that has kept me away from implementing this is, how client will ask the server to send its feeds. Even if the client pokes the server about the feed, how will the server send them or how will the client receive it. One way out could be, the server writes all the feeds to a file and then the client knowing the address of the file parse it extracting the relevant data. But it could be a very long process if the there are many clients connected to the server.

*Note: The client application is a desktop application*

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to identify the client by a unique user string or by authenticating the user. The most common way for implementing this is probably basic authentication (username/password) or a security string.

Basic Auth:
User enters username/password in the client software which is bundled with the feed request using either [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) or [HTTP-BA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Security/Identifier string:
User enters a unique string such as hashed user ID or alike, which the client bundles with the feed request. E.g `https://feed.domain.com?identity=fed54bd54ae...`

Comment: I will identify the client but how does the server send data to a _swing app_

Comment: The server almost never send information to the client when not requested, its the client that requests information. There are ways of pushing information to the client but there are obstacles; you must have the client to listen for the server-notification, and you must always be sure that the client ip has not been changed. Trust me, you are better of having the client request information instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of ways to differentiate clients. Imagine what you will do when you go to a store. Do you just stand there, waiting for the cashier to give you something? No, you ask for something. How you implement that is up to you. You can use different ports, different URLs, define the protocol so that the client passes the name or id of the wanted resource when it connects.... Nothing really special here.

Comment: ports ? URLS ? Can you please explain HOW. I don't understand how will the server be able to send feeds to _swing app_.I know how to poke the server, for the want of feeds but not the other way round

Comment: You do realize that it's bi-directional communication (at least in the case of Sockets, HTTP or several other mechanisms). The Swing app connects to the server and the server responds to the app. It's really basic networking, so if this is unclear to you, you should really go through some tutorials.

Comment: Yes I do realize this. But I haven't found any means to write data to app stream.

Comment: There is no such a thing as an "app stream". What are you using to transmit data? HttpURLConnection? Socket?

Comment: application sends data to the server using `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: You didn't answer me.Application sends data to the server using `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: @SuhailGupta And through the same HttpURLConnection you get the data back, when you call the connection's getInputStream() method.

Comment: I didn't get you exactly.Do you want me to have a separate URL for each of the client ?

Comment: Of course not. A HTTPUrlConnection is a 2-way connection. First the client connects to the server with some information, then the server responds to it. I really don't understand what is so difficult about this. Maybe you need to read up on networking, sockets and HTTP.

Comment: Like I said before: connection.getInputStream(). I'm surprised you're asking here and not Googling. It would be faster that way.

Comment: You don't understand me ! What do I read from the URL..? The feeds ? [I know the way](http://i42.tinypic.com/selt36.jpg) but what do I read from it. Please explain. How am I going to place feeds onto that

Comment: You read whatever the server returns! If you have a servlet running there, written and controlled by you, you can decide whatever you want to return, such as HTML, JSON, XML, or any other content. I sincerely hope that this is a hobby project and not a work project.